# How to convert a string that include hex to hex in Perl?

Tags: string, perl, hex

For example, I have a string `"\x80\x81\x82.abc\x00"`, then it should be converted to hex `8081822e61626300`. May I ask how to do it in Perl?

Comment: Your code is like what? [Edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11325844/edit) to put the code in. (See [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)).

Answer (score 3):

*Do you have string* `"\x80\x81\x82.abc\x00"` *or* `'\x80\x81\x82.abc\x00'`*?*

***Option 1:***

```
my $text = "\x80\x81\x82.abc\x00";
$text = unpack "H*", $text;
print $text;
```

***Option 2:***

```
my $text = '\x80\x81\x82.abc\x00';
$text =~ s/\\x([a-zA-Z\d]{2})/{chr hex $1}/ge;
$text = unpack "H*", $text;
print $text;
```

Answer (score 0):

`unpack 'H*'` is likely the best solution:

```
$ perlsh
eval: unpack "H*", "\x80\x81\x82.abc\x00"
'8081822e61626300'
```

Comment: Yes, if you directly input the string in the unpack, then you will get the correct result, but in my here, I use var, like $string = "\x80\x81\x82.abc\x00", then the output is not correct, it converted single char (such as "\" ,"x" ,"8","0") into hex, not "\x80", that's what I expect.

Comment: @chao: See @Ωmega's answer. He has both possibilities. There's a difference between `"` and `'` in Perl. `"` turns `\x80` into hex while `'` leaves it as a string.